# how to handle NSNumberFormatter issue in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

I am Creating an application with multiple textfields. I would like when the user enters a number in the textfield, to automatically add the dollar symbol when editing ends. Right now, When i editing the textfield is changed like $0.00. But i need to edit the previous value is $5,000.00 but when i add the 0 in the text field to change $500,000.00. But I only get the output $0.00 how can i handle this issue?

Comment: It's not very clear what you expect to happen, and what's happening.  Why don't you post some code to show how you're doing it, and what you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"begin editing=$%f",[firstnametextfield.text floatValue]);
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"end editing=$%f",[firstnametextfield.text floatValue]);
}
```

input is 500,

output will be,
  begin editing=$0.000000
  end editing=$500.000000

so you should read the textfield.text in `textFieldDidEndEditing:` or`textFieldShouldReturn:` ..